# php5.4 autoloading traits

Tags: php, autoload, traits

Are traits in php5.4 subject to autoloading?

I've not yet got an environment to test in, but I can't see any mention of it on __autoload at php.net or on the traits page, but it seems traits behave like classes in some regards.

Has anyone tried this yet?

**UPDATE:**

I found a request here:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61265 (2012-03-03 13:10 UTC)

that seems to suggest it does work, but not explicitly.  Can anyone confirm that a straight __autoload() will be called for a missing trait?

**UPDATE:** Confirmed - it works as expected - __autoload will fetch traits, although getting php5.4 to work first time seems to be bigger challenge.

Thanks,
MyStream

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to the manual, the [**`trait_exists()`**](http://fr.php.net/trait_exists) function takes a boolean as second parameter, that is related to autoloading; which seems to indicate that traits and autoload are not two incompatible ideas.

In addition, if you take a look at the source-code of that [**`trait_exists()`**](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#1284) function, you'll see a section of code, conditioned by that second parameter, that looks quite similar to what you can see in the source-code of [**`class_exists()`**](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#1200).

So, I'd say a second time that traits and autoload are not incompatible ideas ;-)

*(I don't have PHP 5.4 installed on my current computer, so I cannot test by myself -- but, looking at the code...)*

---

**[edit]** OK, I've just compiled **PHP 5.4.3**, the current stable version:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php --version
PHP 5.4.3 (cli) (built: May 17 2012 21:11:42)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Let's try the following short portion of code, which is saved as `temp-2.php`, and tries to use a trait that is not declared in this file:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($name) {
    echo "AUTOLOAD :: ";
    var_dump($name);
});

class MyClass {
    use MyTrait;   // Let's try to use a trait that is not declared in this file
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->plop();
```

Basically, if autoloading works for traits, `"AUTOLOAD"` and the name of my trait should be displayed.

So, let's try executing that portion of code -- and here is the result I get:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php ./temp-2.php
AUTOLOAD :: string(7) "MyTrait"

Fatal error: Trait 'MyTrait' not found in /.../temp-2.php on line 13
```

So, the autoloading function *(here, an anonymous one -- but that doesn't change a thing)* is called...

... which means that **traits are, with PHP 5.4.3, subject to autoloading**.

Comment: Not only did you install it, but you also tested and provided a very good answer. +1 excellent reply. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :-) *(I wanted to install 5.4 since a long time -- I've finally done it ^^)*

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed as well:

```
PHP 5.4.3-1~dotdeb.0 (cli) (built: May  8 2012 20:49:26)

Fatal error: Trait 'x' not found in /.../index.php on line 12
```

They are treated as classes because they are implemented as (modiffied?) classes.

For example they currently have a residual behaviour from classes: they can own properties.

In theory they shouldn't and you  shouldn't rely on them having this ability. In the future it will probably be phased out.

Comment: Thank you for that - very useful answer and advice. +1 It will be very interesting to see how it develops.

Comment: IMO it's a very bad/clumsy syntax.

Allowing properties in traits (if it continues). B.asically allows for "full" multiple inheritance.

I had been excited to test this feature just like I was about namespaces back @php5.3, and again disappointment.

Comment: Also in php5.4 we have direct function return value resolution: explode(' ', 'Mihai Stancu')[1] == 'Stancu', and array syntax ['key' => 'value'].

Comment: I don't like namespaces or their php implementation, but functional traits look very useful to me at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, but as opposed to the old "mix-ins" we used to work with which could be dynamically loaded, this is pretty weak. You know the ones when you had to define an array of "mixed-in" class-names or class_names=>method_names?

Comment: Yeah - I remember :) - the same concept has made its way into CSS (SASS et al)  I'm not opposed to the idea - mostly implementation, but happy that Traits provide a way to ease bloat in PHP without enforcing unusual inheritance patterns of namespaces or interfaces for the sake of additional functionality.